# GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework is in an invalid or unknown format and cannot be processed

Tags: c#, visual-studio, maui

I encountered an error -
XamarinBuildDownloadCache/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework is in an invalid or unknown format and cannot be processed.

The error only occurs when building on iOS

If I'm not mistaken, the error appeared after updating vs to 17.7.5, but I'm not sure that it was caused by this, but I didn't do anything before that either.

I tried to find who had encountered this error but didn’t really find anything, only three links where there is no answer to this question

[image: nuget packages used in iOS]

Comment: 1. Is it a MAUI app? 2. What NuGet packages have you installed? Are you using the `Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds`?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Yes, this is a MAUI application. I added the packages used in the project to the question. Xamarin.Google.iOS.MobileAds - as you can see, I don’t use such a package

Comment: I think the issue is related with the package: `Plugin.Firebase`, also, is it a release build? Can you try this workaround:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/12863?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thanks for the answer, I'll try it. I compile in both release and debug, the error is the same.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Checked and the workaround doesn't work for me. I also removed Plugin.Firebase and the project builds without it. I will continue to look for solutions

Comment: I am also having this problem in xamarin.iOS project where I reference the MobileAds nuget. Very frustrating.

Comment: @KoMa Thanks for the response, can you confirm you can compile it successfully if remove the Plugin.Firebase and Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Yes, I am successfully creating a project on iOS without these packages.

Comment: @KoMa You can try to remove the packages and then manually delete files in C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\XamarinBuildDownloadCache, readd the packages one at a time. If it fails, repeat the step.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT I didn't quite understand "read one at a time". Should I delete the folders one by one and try to build the application?
I also tried deleting the folder completely, but that didn't help.

Comment: @KoMa First delete the files under XamarinBuildDownloadCache and then add the package:Plugin.Firebase and then repeat that operation for the package:Plugin.Firebase.Crashlytics

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Thank you, but I found a temporary solution to this problem [link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/19173#issuecomment-1765906924)

Comment: @KoMa No worries, can you help confirm if this temporary solution works on your side?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Yes it works

Comment: @KoMa Thanks for the response, have a great day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> XamarinBuildDownloadCache/GAppM-8.9.1/GoogleAppMeasurement-8.9.1/Frameworks/GoogleAppMeasurement.xcframework
> is in an invalid or unknown format and cannot be processed.

For those who met the above error when building MAUI iOS, please try the workaround below to fix it provided by [Rolf](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/19173#issuecomment-1765906924) and thanks to @KoMa pointed this out:

1. Locate the file Xamarin.Shared.targets - it's probably something
   like `C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.iOS.Sdk\16.4.8968-net8-rc2\tools\msbuild\iOS\Xamarin.Shared.targets`
   and open it in a text editor.
2. Find the `_ExpandNativeReferences` target (around line 140):

```
<Target Name="_ExpandNativeReferences" Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'" DependsOnTargets="_DetectSdkLocations;_ComputeTargetArchitectures;_GenerateBundleName">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_XCFrameworkNativeReference Include="@(NativeReference -> '%(Identity)/.')" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.xcframework'" />
        <_FrameworkNativeReference Include="@(NativeReference -> '%(Identity)/%(Filename)')" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.framework'" />
        <_FileNativeReference Include="@(NativeReference)" Condition="'%(Extension)' != '.framework' And '%(Extension)' != '.xcframework'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ResolveNativeReferences
        SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)"
        Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true' And '$(IsBindingProject)' != 'true'"
        Architectures="$(TargetArchitectures)"
        FrameworksDirectory="$(_AppFrameworksRelativePath)"
        IntermediateOutputPath="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)"
        NativeReferences="@(_XCFrameworkNativeReference);@(_FrameworkNativeReference)"
        References="@(ReferencePath)"
        SdkIsSimulator="$(_SdkIsSimulator)"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(_ComputedTargetFrameworkMoniker)"
        >
        <Output TaskParameter="NativeFrameworks" ItemName="_ResolvedNativeReference" />
    </ResolveNativeReferences>

    <ItemGroup>
        <_FrameworkNativeReference Include="@(_ResolvedNativeReference)" Condition="'%(Kind)' == 'Framework'" />
        <_FileNativeReference Include="@(_ResolvedNativeReference)" Condition="'%(Kind)' == 'Static' Or '%(Kind)' == 'Dynamic'" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

3. Remove the SessionId="$(BuildSessionId)" line, so that it reads:

```
<Target Name="_ExpandNativeReferences" Condition="'$(DesignTimeBuild)' != 'true'" DependsOnTargets="_DetectSdkLocations;_ComputeTargetArchitectures;_GenerateBundleName">
    <ItemGroup>
        <_XCFrameworkNativeReference Include="@(NativeReference -> '%(Identity)/.')" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.xcframework'" />
        <_FrameworkNativeReference Include="@(NativeReference -> '%(Identity)/%(Filename)')" Condition="'%(Extension)' == '.framework'" />
        <_FileNativeReference Include="@(NativeReference)" Condition="'%(Extension)' != '.framework' And '%(Extension)' != '.xcframework'" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ResolveNativeReferences
        Condition="'$(IsMacEnabled)' == 'true' And '$(IsBindingProject)' != 'true'"
        Architectures="$(TargetArchitectures)"
        FrameworksDirectory="$(_AppFrameworksRelativePath)"
        IntermediateOutputPath="$(DeviceSpecificIntermediateOutputPath)"
        NativeReferences="@(_XCFrameworkNativeReference);@(_FrameworkNativeReference)"
        References="@(ReferencePath)"
        SdkIsSimulator="$(_SdkIsSimulator)"
        TargetFrameworkMoniker="$(_ComputedTargetFrameworkMoniker)"
        >
        <Output TaskParameter="NativeFrameworks" ItemName="_ResolvedNativeReference" />
    </ResolveNativeReferences>

    <ItemGroup>
        <_FrameworkNativeReference Include="@(_ResolvedNativeReference)" Condition="'%(Kind)' == 'Framework'" />
        <_FileNativeReference Include="@(_ResolvedNativeReference)" Condition="'%(Kind)' == 'Static' Or '%(Kind)' == 'Dynamic'" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

4. Try to build again.

Comment: This works in Visual Studio 17.7.5 and 17.8.0 Preview 4, just restart both your Mac and your Windows PC after the changes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, you can try the posted solution if it still doesn't work after restarting.